# Wrong day_of_month after popBackStack

Tags: android

The result is correct when I start the application (today = 30).
But if I go to another fragment and if I use back button (popbackstack), the
value of **day_of_month** is always 1.

The rest is always correct (year, month, hour, ..)

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

protected final Calendar calendar;
private CalendarAdapter calendarAdapter;

public CalendarFragment() {
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    locale = Locale.getDefault();
}

...

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final RelativeLayout calendarLayout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar, null);

    Log.v("today : ", "today"+calendar.getTimeInMillis()+" / "+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use your code in OnResume to run every time you come in your fragment or activity.
when you write your code in onCreate, it run just first time you create the page.